# Why would browsers not give complete API control over HTTP2 frames from JavaScript?

Tags: browser, http2, grpc-web

> But gRPC cannot be used properly inside browsers, because they don’t (and probably will not) provide sufficient API to control HTTP2 frames from JavaScript.
> (https://medium.com/@denis.zhbankov/grpc-web-via-http2-b05c8c8f9e6)

I don't understand why this would be the case? Is it cause of some security issue or some technical challenges? All the documentation for gRPC-Web just says you can't do it, but no one really explains why browsers might never give complete control over HTTP2 on JavaScript. So am hoping someone could explain why?

Comment: You should ask the author of that blog post why they think that is the case (presumably Medium allows for comments?). Not only is it a subjective statement, but it also attempts to predict the future.

Comment: @TylerH well I thought I should do that too, but that is an article from an year ago so... thought I wouldn't get a response, but I guess giving it a try wouldn't hurt. But yea it's not the only place where it says that, says that in a few different articles also I think, so am wondering and really confused.